# SAML SSO Authentication with Django REST Framework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on, saml

I'm currently working on a AngularJS front-end and Django REST back-end. I've been using [django-rest-auth](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth) in the past to authenticate my connections between the two, but I now have to integrate a SSO authentication using SAML.

I've looked around and decided to use [python3-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/python3-saml), but any of the documentation and use case examples (for this package and any other) are applied for pure Django applications.

I've been basing myself on OneLogin's [django/flask guide](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/python) and I tried making a custom Middleware that would catch my requests, but the implementation of the redirects provided by OneLogin does not work with REST call (obviously). I've also seen some people using the AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS Django setting and I'm wondering if it's maybe more what I'm looking for.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after more research and trials, I've gone with [django_saml2_auth](https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth) instead. It's pretty much plug and play, but I had to remove Token authentication and use Basic and Session authentication.

Comment: Saml2 works with python2.x. I am using python3.6. Could you please give more info on integration? How you integrated? How are you maintaining session after integration?

Comment: @JyotiradityaParmar, it does appear to work with python3.6. Take a look at the github repo for compatible versions of Python and Django. https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth#django-saml2-authentication-made-easy