# Configurable SAML SSO Authentication in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, multi-tenant

Looking for insight into a use case in Django REST Framework (DRF) and supporting customer defined authentication method: TokenAuthentication (by default), SAML 2.0 SSO, OAuth2 federated login. The method is set per customer account. I know I would enable SAML 2.0 support for all users in DRF, but I don't see how to have each user account in our software use their own Auth engine, method and settings. DRF seems to want an all or nothing configuration.

I'm aware of both [django-saml2-auth plugin](https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth) and this StackOverflow question [SAML SSO Authentication with Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473893/saml-sso-authentication-with-django-rest-framework)

django-saml2-auth is a great plugin and is likely involved in the solution, but I see no examples of how to have multiple different authentication methods on a per account in your app.

More details:
I want to allow a per customer method of supporting account settings enabling the option to select one of multiple authenticate methods such as TokenAuthentication (by default), or SSO and providing SAML 2.0 or Oauth2 setting. Every account could select from the enabled methods. DRF seems to expect a single authentication provider to be enabled. Not grokking how to do this in this framework yet. Currently using TokenAuthentication as the default authentication system. TokenAuthentication would remain the default provider for most accounts. I need to be able to allow more sophisticated enterprise customers to switch authentication methodology. That's the challenge. Adding SAML2 is simple. Using OAuth2 is simple. Allow any of them to be chosen by accounts, with each account having their own authentication workflow. This is quite a different requirement than the use case that django-saml2-auth solves. That plugin may be involved in the solution, but the limitation here seems to be the model DRF uses to define the authentication provider. I've scanned the DRF, and django-saml2-auth docs, code and examples. Nothing I've seen anticipates this.

My current working theory is that I could make it possible with a little creative thinking. Perhaps there's a different URL mapping that utilizes different login/authentication method. The logged in data token that must be provided in subsequent calls could have a custom validation method that works with all supported protocols without large new blocks of code. So my instinct is the problem is mapping the login process to something that is not universal and requires some type of pre-fetching of account configuration. My proposed solution there is in the login URL for the enterprise cases. But still DRF seems to still be lacking a method for defining the authentication process per each account. Say I use SAML2 through Okta, You use OneLogin, Another person uses an OAuth2 provider, and most customers use the default native TokenAuthentication. We're all users in the same DRF app. But there isn't a way I see to define authentication engine based on account.

I know there is a possible brute force method of customizing the method being invoked to perform the login action that could be non-standard, query to configuration for a customer, then use either native or a federated identity provider. However, I'm hoping there are more DRF grokking folks that know of other strategies to enable this functionality.

I understand that there is a chicken and egg syndrome in that until you know something about the customer making the request you won't know what their configuration is. We will most likely need to support a different login URL for enterprise customers who enable SAML. That way you could load the customer's configuration. Perhaps we would do something like use a URL like so: www.myproduct/login/the_customer_company. Being new to Django REST Framework I am not super clear how to wire up different methods of authentication within the Django settings.py or urls.py? The default new user configuration would remain TokenAuthentication based but on request a customer could configure SAML and use a different URL including the company name. Hopefully my question is clear. I see how to configure DRF to use SAML SSO instead of TokenAuthentication, but I want to allow customer configured settings.

DRF and the django-saml2-auth approaches seem to be "all or nothing" and provide a single authentication provider mapping for the application. I would love to be wrong about that limitation!

Comment: The project I'm currently working on will soon also face this 'problem' so I keep my eyes open when browsing the web and I recently ran into this Django plugin. It's been around for a while, but they recently added some support for DRF. I havent looked into it very extensively, but might be worth checking out for you: [dango-saml2-auth](https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth) Let me know if this is something you think offers a solution

Comment: Different than django-saml2-auth as I explain above.It switches Django's authentication provider globally, not as needed.Imagine you need all: TokenAuthentication by default, SAML 2 and Oauth2 in s single app.  Django and that plugin show no signs of supporting that model. Imagine I have a product that is used by small companies/individual practitioners up to the largest enterprise. An account is created. ENterprise enabled accounts may opt to connect the system to their existing SAML 2.0. Another might prefer Oatuh2. Django REST framework doesn't really like per account auth provider.

Comment: @RichSadowsky I'm curious if you can provide an update on what solution you ended up implementing. There is this fairly abandoned djangsaml2_tenant project https://github.com/eabglobal/djangosaml2_tenant that is probably not much use but worth mentioning.

Comment: @PierreDrescher I can't provide an update because my team at the time did the actual implementation in Ukraine. I left the project before the development was complete. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One option to achieve this would be to use an Identity Provider (IdP) that can act as an identity broker, for example [Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/). Configured this way, your Django app would be configured for SAML authentication with the single IdP. The IdP can then be configured for whatever upstream SAML / OAuth identity providers it supports depending on the customer requirements.

How you get the users to the right upstream identity provider and still have a good user experience would have a few options. The two most obvious ones would be to either configure a custom URL for each user group, and have that URL redirect to the correct IdP landing page when logging on. Alternately you could perhaps have a login page on the Django site that asked for their login / email address (without password), and when they entered that it looked up the IdP URL associated with that user and then to sent them to the right place.

While this is not a Django module / code solution for the problem, it simplifies the authentication on the Django side, and decouples the authentication to an external service specifically designed to do auth, providing the app with more flexibility (and probably more security).